# "Preg_Replace" Function Issue with Single/Double Quotes

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to replace some pieces of codes in different theme files using the below function, however, I am stuck with the second part of the function where I want to replace some PHP code which contains a single quote.

When I run the function, the only part changes is the first part.

```
function update_GTour_theme_files()
{
    $new_update = file_get_contents("/home/tourieuw/public_html/wp-content/themes/grandtour/header.php");
    $new_update = preg_replace('/\$page_menu_transparent = 1/', '\$page_menu_transparent = 0', $new_update);
    $new_update = preg_replace('/\$grandtour_page_menu_transparent = 1/', '\$grandtour_page_menu_transparent = 0', $new_update);
    if (file_put_contents("/home/tourieuw/public_html/wp-content/themes/grandtour/header.php", $new_update)) {
        $errpass = TRUE;
    } else {
        $errmsg  = "Header.php was not updated";
        $errpass = FALSE;
    }

    $new_update_2 = file_get_contents("/home/tourieuw/public_html/wp-content/themes/grandtour/templates/template-tour-header.php");
    $new_update_2 = preg_replace('/(esc_html(grandtour_format_tour_price($tour_price)))/', '\'From \'.esc_html(grandtour_format_tour_price($tour_price)', $new_update_2);
    if (file_put_contents("/home/tourieuw/public_html/wp-content/themes/grandtour/templates/template-tour-header.php", $new_update_2)) {
        $errpass = TRUE;
    } else {
        $errmsg  = "template-tour-header.php was not updated";
        $errpass = FALSE;
    }

    if ($errpass = TRUE) {
        echo '</br><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold;">Changes were applied successfully.</span>';
    } else {
        echo '</br><span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">' . $errmsg . '</span>';
    }
}
```

I am expecting when running this function that both variables in two files will be replaced with this code

Comment: Whoa, what? Show a sample of minimal input followed by the incorrect output. You really expect people to dig through that much code?

Comment: _You really expect people to dig through that much code?..._ How many lines of code do you see there? @MonkeyZeus

Comment: @B001ᛦ Too many for the issue described

Comment: _the only part changes is the first part._ Which is the first part?

Comment: @B001ᛦ`    $new_update = file_get_contents("/home/tourieuw/public_html/wp-content/themes/grandtour/header.php");
    $new_update = preg_replace('/\$page_menu_transparent = 1/', '\$page_menu_transparent = 0', $new_update);
    $new_update = preg_replace('/\$grandtour_page_menu_transparent = 1/', '\$grandtour_page_menu_transparent = 0', $new_update);
    if (file_put_contents("/home/tourieuw/public_html/wp-content/themes/grandtour/header.php", $new_update)) {
        $errpass = TRUE;
    } else {
        $errmsg  = "Header.php was not updated";
        $errpass = FALSE;
    }`